# Button name shows dots in IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7

i got this problem only in IOS 7 and before i have read question on Stack overflow but could not find the one.

i have buttons in my APP (UISegmented) like back button text is Back, but suddenly middle of operation or when another view load on top of view, bottom view back button will show text as Ba.. also other buttons will change in text with dots in it…

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Back", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 28);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:137.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(handleBackButton:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItemLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
```

i had came across similar question here but at present could not find the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is in your code segment control button name is not setting properly. So should try for setting the button title using below api:-

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title    
  forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```